# Help with Sharepoint (WSS 3.0) and JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, oauth, wss

Ok so the scenario is as follows:

Have a sharepoint site setup on Microsoft Online, basically this site is a job booking system and is based on a custom sharepoint list.

What I am trying to achieve is to extract List Items where the Invoiced Column is set to "No". Eventually I would like to post this to xero.com using their API as it accepts XML through the API Endpoints. Have tried using JQuery and JPoint but my limited programming skills are holding me back.

Could anyone offer me some advice or point me in the right direction of someone that could help?

am willing to pay someone if they can help me with getting this to work :)

Comment: Could you post the relevant html source (start of the table tag + 1 row)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using JavaScript and WSS web services to query the data and handle the response?

You could use something like this:

```
function wssWebServiceAccess() 
{
var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>LIST NAME</listName> \
                <query><Query> \
                      <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>1</Value></Eq></Where> \
                </Query></query> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                        </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://WSS_SITE/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: showResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
}

function showResult(xData, status)
{
    alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
}
```

This is a bit rough round the edges and may need a bit of tweaking but I hope it gives you a bit of a head start.

If you don't have to do it via JavaScript, you could use an applicaiton (i.e. a Console Application written in Visual Studio) that uses WSS web services to retrieve the data, handle it and then pass it to wherever you need it to go.

Hope this all helps...